# How does multiplying by 66049 duplicate bits?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, alphablending

This is part of a pixel blending operation to enhance precision.

```
typedef unsigned uint;

uint h(uint x) {
    x &= 0xff;
    return x << 8 | x;
}

uint g(uint x, uint y) {
    return h(x) * h(y) >> 24;
}
```

I looked at the compiler output, and found a very interesting line.

```
g:
        movzx   edi, dil
        movzx   esi, sil
        imul    esi, edi
        imul    eax, esi, 66049  # <---
        shr     eax, 24
        ret
```

This can be decompiled as,

```
uint g_(uint x, uint y) {
    return (x & 0xff) * (y & 0xff) * 66049 >> 24;
}
```

I couldn't understand how multiplying by `66049` can produce the desired result. What is the math behind it?

Comment: GCC always print constants in decimal in asm source.  If you're using https://godbolt.org/, mouseover a constant to see it in hex; often that's more interesting for "magic" constants.

Comment: @PeterCordes I typed the number in a programming calculator before asking this question. The binary representation is quite confusing because it is 1 - 6 zeros - 1 - 7 zeros - 1. I'd have easily noticed the trick if the number was `0x101`, but with two of this combined, it was quite confusing.

Comment: Yeah, it's non-obvious, not saying that would have fully answered your question.  But pretty clearly it's going to be something about bit-positions, so it would be sensible to write it in hex in your SO question.  Only ever writing it in decimal in your question seems almost naive.  Not exactly a lack of research effort, but it seemed like you hadn't even considered looking at it in hex, where it's a much "simpler" number, so pretty likely to be the key to figuring out how it works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

66049 is 0x10201 hexadecimal. That's the big clue, since:

```
(x << 8 | x) = (x * 0x101)
```

(assuming 0 ≤ x ≤ 0xFF), then `(x << 8 | x) * (y << 8 | y)` is the same as `x * y * 0x101 * 0x101`.

The `0x101 * 0x101` can be reduced to `0x10201` - there's your magic constant.

So why is `x * 0x101` the same as `(x << 8 | x)`? That should be easy to see with a decimal example. If you multiply any number 0-99 by 101, it duplicates the digits - for example, 32 * 101 = 3232. This is because multiplying by 100 effectively just adds 0s at the end (i.e. 32 * 100 = 3200) and the extra 1 just adds the original value (32 * 101 = 32 * 100 + 32 * 1 = 3200 + 32 = 3232). The same principle applies in hexadecimal (or in binary).